# Nuxt com tradução global dinâmica do i18n

Tags: javascript, i18n, vue.js

Minha configuração no nuxt.config.js

```
i18n: {
    locales: [
      { code: 'pt-br', iso: 'pt-BR', file: 'pt-BR.js' },
      { code: 'eng', iso: 'en-US', file: 'en-US.js' },
      { code: 'esp', iso: 'es-ESP', file: 'es-ESP.js' }
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'pt-br',
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    vueI18nLoader: true,
    strategy: 'no_prefix'
  }
```

Não é possível alterar o idioma através do aplicativo somente através da plataforma onde ele é alocado;
O backend nos fornece as informações do usuário, como por exemplo a linguagem e nós armazenamos através da vuex.

O grande problema é que quando existe essa alteração no idioma, eu não tenho um arquivo "global" para por exemplo utilizar do `this.$i18n.setLocale(this.user.language)`. Existe alguma forma de configurar isso dentro do nuxt.config.js pra que ele pegue dinamicamente isso?

Answer (score 0):

Uma fora de se fazer é durante o bootstrap do seu app, (geralmente em app.vue) você tente identificar o idioma do navegador utilizando o `navigator.language`, desse modo você pode setar o valor que correto ao carregar a aplicação

```js
if(this.user.isLogged){
   this.$i18n.setLocale(this.user.language)
} else if(navigator.language === 'pt-BR'){
   this.$i18n.setLocale('pt-BR')
} else {
   this.$i18n.setLocale('en-US')
}
```

O código acima é apenas um norteador para você começar a criar uma solução própria.

Boa sorte